# How to use Magick++ to convert YUYV to RGB?

Tags: c++, imagemagick, yuv, magick++

Reading images from a device via V4L2.  The images are in YUV 4:2:2 format, aka V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV, aka YUY2.

What I'd like to do is either convert the blob of bytes to RGB, or better yet how to instantiate a Magick++ Image object and tell it the data is in YUYV instead of RGB24.

Can this be easily done?  The Magick++ documentation is bare-bones and provides zero help:  http://www.imagemagick.org/api/Magick++/classMagick_1_1Image.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily convert `YUV422` to `RGB888`. Let `data` be the image data you load in `YUV422` format then:

```
u  = data[0];
y1 = data[1];
v  = data[2];
y2 = data[3];
...
...
```

and then:

```
rgb[0] = yuv2rgb(y1, u, v);
rgb[1] = yuv2rgb(y2, u, v);
...
...
```

using the following formula for `yuv2rgb`:

```
R = Y + 1.140*V
G = Y - 0.395*U - 0.581*V
B = Y + 2.032*U
```

Answer (score 1):

DimChtz's answer would be the easiest, as the task is straight forward.

ImageMagick does support the formats

```
     UYVY* rw-   16bit/pixel interleaved YUV
      YUV* rw-   CCIR 601 4:1:1 or 4:2:2
```

And can be leveraged by [magick++](/questions/tagged/magick%2b%2b) something like...

```cpp
 // Quickly reorder YUYV to UYVY
 unsigned char y1, u, y2, v;
 for ( int i = 0; i < buffer_length; i+=4 ) {
     y1 = buffer[i  ];
     u  = buffer[i+1];
     y2 = buffer[i+2];
     v  = buffer[i+3];
     buffer[i  ] = u;
     buffer[i+1] = y1;
     buffer[i+2] = v;
     buffer[i+3] = y2;
 }
 Magick::Image image;
 Magick::Blob blob( buffer, buffer_length );
 image.size("176x144");
 image.magick("UYVY");
 image.read(blob);
 // ... etc ...
```

I would suggest jumping over to ImageMagick's [ImageMagick Program Interfaces](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=23) board, and issue a feature request and/or seek guidance.

Comment: Awesome answer.  How did you get the 2 lines of text following "ImageMagick does support the formats"?  Is that part of the output of a tool?

Comment: Yes sir. It's from IM's identify utility. `identify -list format`

Comment: Hmmm. Must be for newer versions. I'm on magick++6.q16-5 on Debian (ARM7 device) and this doesn't exist:  $ identify -list format
-bash: identify: command not found

Comment: I would expected the `identity` utility would be included in [`imagemagick-6.q16`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/arm64/imagemagick-6.q16/filelist) package, yet you may have only installed the magick++ library.